# How to convert JPG image to WEBP format in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, multer, webp

I m trying to upload an image using react.Js and save that image in node.Js using multer middleware. This is working perfectly but now I want to convert that image to WEBP  format using webp-converter which is a small vice- versa.

But I m getting this error :

```
 Error: Command failed: E:\Zegal\node_modules\webp-converte
 ib/libwebp_win64/bin/cwebp.exe -q 80 2a3279b820cc23939eea0295228423ee-- 
 inspironal-quote-about-life-inspiring-words.jpg -o output.webp
 SHCreateStreamOnFileA(filename, STGM_READ, stream) failed 80070002
 Error opening input file 2a3279b820cc23939eea0295228423ee--inspirational-quo
 about-life-inspiring-words.jpg (80070002)
 OpenInputStream(filename, &stream) failed 80070002
 cannot open input file '2a3279b820cc23939eea0295228423ee--inspirational-quot
 bout-life-inspiring-words.jpg'
 Error! Could not process file 2a3279b820cc23939eea0295228423ee--inspirationa
 uote-about-life-inspiring-words.jpg
 Error! Cannot read input picture file '2a3279b820cc23939eea0295228423ee--ins
 ational-quote-about-life-inspiring-words.jpg'
```

How can I solve this problem in node using multer and WEBP ? Is there any
other solution for conversion ?

```
const multer = require('multer');
const webp = require('webp-converter');
const path = require('path');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './public/images',
    filename(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`)
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage,
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        checkFileType(file, cb)
    }
}).single("image");

checkFileType = (file, cb) => {
    console.log("check file", file);
    const requireMimetype = "image/jpeg";
    const checkMimeType = file.mimetype == requireMimetype ? true : false;
    console.log("checkMimeType", checkMimeType);
    if (checkMimeType) {
        webp.cwebp(file.originalname, "output.webp", "-q 80", function (status) {
            console.log(status);
        });
        return cb(null, true)
    } else {
        cb("Error:Only jpg images are allowed.")
    }
}

module.exports = upload;
```

Comment: I solve this problem.I pass the path of the image from the route to the webp input file . You can reference this : https://github.com/santoshmahat/Image-upload-with-node-and-react

Answer (score 12):

I find sharp a ease way to do so.

```
const sharp = require('sharp');


console.log(req.files.image, "form image is here"); 
console.log(req.files.image.data, "form image buffer data is here");

sharp(req.files.image.data)            
.rotate()            
.resize(200)            
.toBuffer()            
.then( newBuffer => { 

//changing the old jpg image buffer to new webp buffer
 req.files.image.data = newBuffer;

//moving the new webq image to server public folders
 req.files.image.mv(appRoot+'/uploads/images/'+ Date.now() + '.webp', function(err) {                
  if (err) {                    
     return res.status(500).send(err);                
  }
   res.status(200).json({
      message : "image uploaded successfully" 
  })
 })            
})            
.catch( err => { console.log(err) });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 8):

I had used a really awesome image processing library named `sharp`, and one of the features that that library offer is to convert an image into a webp image

```js
import sharp from 'sharp';

const imageProcessing = sharp();

imageProcessing
.webp()
.pipe(someWritableStream);
```

Comment: Hi, can this be used at client side like Angular 7 ? cause I see you are using `import` statement to called the file

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it will work at all, since sharp is a NodeJS wrapper for the library which is written in C and C++(and others non JS language)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to use [fast-image-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-image-server).

In this case, you don't need to convert the file to webp format.
Instead just access the webp file instead of the jpg file.
The library will do the conversion to webp format.
It also caches the image.